# QMessageBox result as a buttonrole

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox, qt5.7

I wanna get result of QMessagebox as a buttonrole. but result always 16384 or 65536
I dont wantto use standartresults, want to use only buttonrole kind of buttons. what am I doing wrong here ? 
(Im very newbie in QT)

```
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        QMessageBox msgBox;
        QPushButton *a=msgBox.addButton("OK",QMessageBox::ActionRole);
        QPushButton *b=msgBox.addButton("CANCEL",QMessageBox::RejectRole);

        int result=msgBox.question(this,"Hola","My 1st Msg");
        //result always return 16384 or 65536(integer) PROBLEM HERE
        if(result==QMessageBox::RejectRole)
            this->setWindowTitle("rejected");
        else
            this->setWindowTitle("accepted");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `question` method is static. It doesn't use the message box you have above. The first 3 lines of your method essentially don't do anything.

Here's what your method really does:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    int result = QMessageBox::question(this,"Hola","My 1st Msg");
    [...]
}
```

Alas, the `QMessageBox` has a long-standing bug: it ignores (!) the custom button roles when it comes to acceptance or rejection of the dialog. While the role is passed to the underlying `QDialogButtonBox`, it is not interpreted correctly when the button is clicked.

Although you can get the role back using `QMessageBox::buttonRole`, the `QMessageBoxPrivate::_q_buttonClicked` invokes `QDialog::done` with the **index** of the button.

Thus, the first button you add will cause the dialog to be rejected, the second one will cause it to be accepted, and further buttons will cause neither. The acceptance/rejection ignores the role completely and is only based on the index of the button, due to the order it was added in.

Thus you should not use the `rejected`/`accepted` signals, unless the first two buttons map directly to these roles in this order, and should use the `buttonClicked` signal and obtain the role of the button directly:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   auto box = new QMessageBox{this};
   box->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
   box->addButton("OK", QMessageBox::ActionRole);
   box->addButton("CANCEL", QMessageBox::RejectRole);
   box->setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
   box->setWindowTitle("Hola");
   box->setText("My 1st message.");
   box->show();

   connect(box, &QMessageBox::buttonClicked, [=](QAbstractButton *button){
      switch (box->buttonRole(button)) {
      case QMessageBox::AcceptRole: return setWindowTitle("accept-role");
      case QMessageBox::ActionRole: return setWindowTitle("action-role");
      case QMessageBox::RejectRole: return setWindowTitle("reject-role");
      }
   });
}
```

Alas, there's another problem: the dialog will be also rejected by closing it via the platform's window manager (the close button on the dialog's title bar). So you need to be able to use the `rejected` signal, but not when it's in error. It's best to factor this functionality out to a `MessageBoxAdapter` class that will only emit correct `accepted` and `rejected` signals:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/messagebox-roles-40753898
#include <QtWidgets>

class MessageBoxAdapter : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   MessageBoxAdapter(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {
      watch(parent);
   }
   void watch(QObject *obj) {
      auto box = qobject_cast<QMessageBox*>(obj);
      if (!box) return;
      connect(box, &QMessageBox::rejected, [=]{
         if (!box->clickedButton()) emit rejected();
      });
      connect(box, &QMessageBox::buttonClicked, [=](QAbstractButton *button){
         auto role = box->buttonRole(button);
         if (role == QMessageBox::AcceptRole) emit accepted();
         else if (role == QMessageBox::RejectRole) emit rejected();
         emit roleClicked(role);
      });
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void accepted();
   Q_SIGNAL void rejected();
   Q_SIGNAL void roleClicked(QMessageBox::ButtonRole role);
};
```

And some user interface to try it out:

```
struct Ui : public QWidget {
   QVBoxLayout layout{this};
   QTextBrowser browser;
   QPushButton button{"Open"};
   MessageBoxAdapter adapter{this};
public:
   Ui() {
      layout.addWidget(&browser);
      layout.addWidget(&button);
      connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Ui::onClicked);
      connect(&adapter, &MessageBoxAdapter::accepted, [=]{ browser.append("accepted"); });
      connect(&adapter, &MessageBoxAdapter::rejected, [=]{ browser.append("rejected"); });
      connect(&adapter, &MessageBoxAdapter::roleClicked, [=](QMessageBox::ButtonRole role){
         browser.append(QStringLiteral("clicked role=%1").arg(role));
      });
   }
   void onClicked() {
      auto box = new QMessageBox{this};
      adapter.watch(box);
      box->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
      box->addButton("OK", QMessageBox::AcceptRole);
      box->addButton("ACTION", QMessageBox::ActionRole);
      box->addButton("CANCEL", QMessageBox::RejectRole);
      box->setIcon(QMessageBox::Question);
      box->setWindowTitle("Hola");
      box->setText("My 1st message.");
      box->show();
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Ui ui;
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```